# csv,pdf, xml supported in freemarker template output

Tags: freemarker

Does freemarker template support output in csv, pdf, html  and xml.

any other java based template framework supporting all these formats.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It supports all kind of text output, like most other template engines as well. Template engines, with some exceptions, don't care what the generated output means. (For PDF you certainly want to generate in some more human-readable format, and then use another software to render it to PDF.)